# How to calculate all possible tuples in natural join operation?

Tags: tuples, relational-algebra, natural-join

I'm trying to finish quiz on Stanford website, it's part of mini course on relational algebra. It goes something like this:

```
Consider a relation R(A,B) with r tuples, all unique within R, and a relation S(B,C) with s tuples, all unique within S.  Let t represent the number of tuples in R natural-join S.  Which of the following triples of values (r,s,t) is possible?

1. (5,10,250)
2. (5,10,500)
3. (2,3,9)
4. (2,10,0)
```

Can someone tell me the right solution and explain why is it the right solution? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maximum and minimum number of tuples in natural join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673235/maximum-and-minimum-number-of-tuples-in-natural-join)

Answer (score 2):

The number of tuples resulting from Natural Join can't be more than the product of the numbers of tuples in each operand. (Natural Join is often described as a filter on the cross-product, for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join_.28.E2.8B.88.29.)

So that rules out answers 1. to 3., leaving 4. as the only possible.